# Row sum with condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a row sum in SQL, but have somewhat complicated logic. for example, I am trying to create a logic with the following table so that

- If A >0 and B > 1, then the sum = A + 2* C + D
- else if A = 0 and B >    1,  then the sum = B + D
- else if A = 0 and B <= 1, then the sum = B +    C
- else if A >0 and B <= 1, then the sum = 2*A + B + C + D

What's the best way to create a logic like this in SQL Server?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
SELECT MySum = CASE WHEN A > 0 AND B > 1 THEN A + 2 * C + D
                    WHEN A = 0 AND B > 1 THEN B + D
                    WHEN A = 0 AND B <= 1 THEN B + C
                    WHEN A > 0 AND B <= 1 THEN 2 * A + B + C + D
                END
FROM T
```